# custom iterator implementation causing memory leaks

Tags: c++, templates, memory-leaks, stl, iterator

I've implemented a random_access_iterator for a custom library (which is templated to be reused both as const iterator and non-const iterator), but it's causing memory leaks while doing something like `std::sort(container.begin(), container.end()` (`container.begin()/end()` return `iterator` instance.

What's wrong with my implementation?

```
template <bool is_const_iterator = false>
class meta_iterator : public std::iterator<std::random_access_iterator_tag, T> {
public:
  typedef T value_type;
  typedef std::ptrdiff_t difference_type;
  typedef typename std::conditional<is_const_iterator, const value_type &,
                                    value_type &> reference;
  typedef std::random_access_iterator_tag iterator_category;
  typedef typename std::conditional<is_const_iterator, value_type const *,
                                    value_type *>::type pointer;
  typedef meta_iterator self_type;

  meta_iterator(T *ptr) : ptr_(ptr) {}

  meta_iterator(const meta_iterator<true> &other) : ptr_(other.ptr_) {}

  self_type operator+(difference_type value) {
    ptr_ += value;
    return *(this);
  };

  self_type operator-(difference_type value) {
    ptr_ -= value;
    return *(this);
  };

  difference_type operator-(const self_type &other) {
    return ptr_ - other.ptr_;
  }

  T &operator[](difference_type value) const { return *ptr_[value]; }
  bool operator==(const self_type &other) const { return ptr_ == other.ptr_; }
  bool operator!=(const self_type &other) const { return !(*this == other); }
  bool operator>=(const self_type &other) const { return !((*this) < other); }
  bool operator<=(const self_type &other) const { return !((*this) > other); }
  bool operator<(const self_type &other) const { return ptr_ < other.ptr_; }
  bool operator>(const self_type &other) const { return ptr_ < other.ptr_; }
  self_type &operator=(const self_type &other) {
    ptr_ = other.ptr_;
    return *(this);
  }
  T *operator->() const { return ptr_; }
  T &operator*() const { return *ptr_; }

  self_type &operator--() {
    ptr_--;
    return *this;
  }

  self_type operator--(int) {
    self_type temp(*this);
    --(*this);
    return (temp);
  }

  self_type &operator++() {
    ptr_++;
    return *this;
  }

  self_type operator++(int) {
    self_type temp(*this);
    --(*this);
    return (temp);
  }

  self_type &operator+=(difference_type value) {
    ptr_ += value;
    return *(this);
  }

  self_type &operator-=(difference_type value) {
    ptr_ -= value;
    return *(this);
  }

  friend class meta_iterator<true>;
  friend class meta_iterator<false>;

private:
  T *ptr_;
};
```

Comment: are you sure, the memory leak is caused by this iterator? How do you determine the memory leak?

Comment: Why do you think the problem is there? Likely 1) the container is leaking 2) the type used in the container is incorrectly implemented (rule of whatever..)

Comment: @cdonat well, it should be. std::sort doesn't depend on container at all (given that `begin()` and `end()` are implemented correctly), so I assume AddressSanitizer points me to the iterator leaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if it causes a memory leak, but these two operators

```
  self_type operator+(difference_type value) {
    ptr_ += value;
    return *(this);
  };

  self_type operator-(difference_type value) {
    ptr_ -= value;
    return *(this);
  };
```

should just return a new iterator, and not update the stored `ptr_`.

Also, there is a typo in

```
  self_type operator++(int) {
    self_type temp(*this);
    --(*this);
    return (temp);
  }
```

making it go in the wrong direction. That will probably confuse some loops.